# Java: "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, variables, symbols

(Rookie mistake, I'm sure.)

I'm a first year computer science student, and attempting to write a program for an assignment, with the code;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab10Ex1 {

   public static void main(String[] arg) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type a number: ");
    int n = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    calcNumFactors();
  }
  public static void calcNumFactors(){

   System.out.print(n + 1);

  }

}
```

But upon compiling, I get the error;

> Lab10Ex1.java:10: error: cannot find symbol    System.out.print(n +
>   1);
>                       ^
>
> symbol:   variable n
>
> location: class Lab10Ex1

If someone could explain to me what I've done wrong, or how to fix it, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just as a tip; keep your code formatting consistent and readable. It'll save a lot of headaches in future assignments and future classes.

Comment: Ah. As I said, I'm new to the site, and new to Java. My apologies. It's probably not helping that it's 1:30 in the morning.

Comment: Yeah, coding into the night is never fun (I did it constantly in college). The formatting bit is almost all for your benefit; it's an absolutely critical skill since you *will* have to work in a team eventually (and the other people have to be able to read your code). From a Stack Overflow perspective, it'll also help you get help much faster (we can't help you if we can't read the code :P)

Comment: Fair enough. On a side note, program done, and, as a bonus, functional. Woo! Good night Internet!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `n` variable was declared in the `main` method and thus is visible only in the main method, nowhere else, and certainly not inside of the `calcNumFactors` method. To solve this, give your `calcNumFactors` method an `int` parameter which would allow calling methods to pass an `int`, such as `n` into the method.

```
public static void calcNumFactors(int number) {
   // work with number in here
}
```

and call it like so:

```
int n = keyboard.nextInt(); 
calcNumFactors(n);
```

Comment: Ah, that fixed it. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

You must declare the variable `n` in `public static void calcNumFactors()`

In your code, you have to pass the value of n as an argument to the function `calcNumFactors()` as Hovercraft Full Of Eels said.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab10Ex1 {

   private static int n;

   public static void main(String[] arg) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please type a number: ");
     n = keyboard.nextInt(); 
    calcNumFactors();
  }
  public static void calcNumFactors(){

   System.out.print(n + 1);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I copied an Enum file from a Grails (.groovy) project and forgot to change the extension to .java