# using method result in another method

Tags: java, methods

```
class Method {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a =1, b=2;
    method1(a,b);
    method2();
 }

 public static int method1(int a, int b) {
    int c = (a + b);
    return c;
 }

 public static void method2() {
   int z=11;
   if (z >= method1(a,b)) {System.out.println("Method 2 works");}
 }   
}
```

-getting [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4KeY.png)error in if statement

Comment: In  method2() u r trying to use parameters a,b but they are not in that method.

Comment: `a` and `b` are method arguments, not result. They are undefined in `method2`. What are you trying to sum in `method2`? What `z` should be greater than?

Comment: You have to pass a and b argument to method2 in order to be consumed by method 1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: "error: cannot find symbol"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20137581/java-error-cannot-find-symbol)

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared variables a and b inside method2, which is causing the error you are seeing.

If you want to use local variables wihthin methods you can try the following:

```
public static void method2() {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int z=11;
    if (z >= method1(a,b)) {System.out.println("Method 2 works");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If method 2 needs resulting input from another methods then you can do in several ways, is more just like a design style

You can do:

```
public static void method2(int x) {
   int z=11;
   if (z >= x) {System.out.println("Method 2 works");}
 }
```

And call it by doing

```
method2(method1(a,b));
```

Answer (score 0):

a,b variables are not global.So those variables are local to those methods in which they are defined.

In method 2 you have not defined a,b variables and tried to access them.

For this pass the variables to method2 also as done for method1 or store the method1 result in a variable and pass that variable to method2 and then compare.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for your help. Finaly I got it. I am trying to learn different ways of applying methods. Now it works fine.

class Method {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1, b = 2, e = 3;
    System.out.println(method1(a, b));
    System.out.println(method2(a, b, e));
    method3();
}

public static int method1(int a, int b) {

    int c = (a + b);
    System.out.print("Method 1 burada işləyir ");
    return c;
}

public static int method2(int a, int b, int e) {
    int q = (a + b + e);

    System.out.print("Method 2 işləyir və nəticə ");

    return q;
}

public static void method3() {
    int z = 11;
    int a = 4;
    int b = 6;
    if (z >= method1(a, b)) {
        System.out.println("Method 3 işləyir");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

package com.ZJAVAKITABI;

class Method {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1, b = 2, e = 3;
    System.out.println(method1(a, b, e));
    System.out.println(method2());
    method3();
    method4();
    System.out.println(method5(a, b));
}

public static int method1(int a, int b, int e) {
    int q = (a + b + e);
    System.out.print("3 parametrli Method 1 işləyir və nəticə ");
    return q;
}

public static int method1(int a, int b) {
    int mf = (a + b);
    System.out.print("2 parametrli Method1 işləyir. Nəticə: ");
    return mf;
}

public static int method2() {
    int a = 4, b = 6;
    int z = a + b;
    System.out.print("Method 2 işləyir və nəticə ");
    return z;
}

public static void method3() {
    System.out.println("Method 3 işləyir, Void nəticə vermir");
}

public static void method4() {
    int v = 5, m = 5;
    int n = v + m;
    System.out.println("Method 4 işləyir, hesablama nəticəsi " + n);
}

public static int method5(int a, int b) {
    int u = 9;
    System.out.print("Method 5 və daxilindəki ");
    int s = method1(a, b) + u + 2; 
    return s;
}
```

}

Comment: It is an answer? Or some edit to the question? Some explanation would be nice!

Comment: this is the final answer what I wanted to test